# BackgroundWorker.IsBusy not 100% reliable?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, backgroundworker

I sometimes get an Exception that my BackgroundWorker is already running after checking it's state with the IsBusy method.

Code:

```
if(!_worker.IsBusy)
    _worker.RunWorkerAsync(stateObj); //<-- exception is thrown here
```

I don't ever call the worker from anywhere else, so I'm stumped on how to handle this. Should I just ignore it? Or have it call itself?

(e.g.)

```
void CallWorker(object stateObj)
{
    try
    {
        if(!_worker.IsBusy)
            _worker.RunWorkerAsync(stateObj);
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        //ignore OR
        //CallWorker(stateObj);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Is it possible that you are calling the CallWorker method in multiple threads? If it is the case, it could be that another thread starts using the _worker between IsBusy and RunWorkerAsync. In which case you should surround the block with a lock(_worker) {} rather than try {} catch

Comment: Oh sorry haven't read properly the quesion... Ignore the previous comment...

Comment: i think that you should call that part of code in thread safe development, or are you calling it in wpf environment?

Comment: Yes, it seems it could. I didn't think it would be possible while planning because it's called from an asynchronous callback, but if it is possible too receive two callbacks simultaneously then that would be the problem. Thanks, and feel free to add your comment as the answer. And you did read it properly, I meant calling the RunWorkerAsync only occurs in the RunWorker method.